# Paypal Hosted Checkout Page (Layout C) Language other than English

Tags: paypal, checkout, hosted, non-english

Is it possible to implement Hosted Checkout Page (Layout C) with French or German languages ?

I've tried to send the following parameter (both to IFrame URL and to the API):
LC=FR

It works fine, but all in English.

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the country of the account signed up for Hosted Sole Solution; French and British accounts can use LC=FR, others cannot.

```
**Account country    available 'lc' parameters**
  United Kingdom     GB, FR
  France             FR, US
  Italy              IT, US
  Spain              ES, US
  Hong Kong          GK, HK
  Australia          AU
  Japan              JP, US
```

If you're using PayPal Payments Advanced ('Payflow Link' with Hosted Checkout Pages); this doesn't support any other languages at this time unfortunately.

Comment: I'm using Payflow Pro account, does it make any difference ?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. Payflow Pro doesn't support any other languages at this time. Updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Robert has situation been changed, or this is still unsupported?